# null arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am Totally new in `android Studio`, I followed a tutorial which i modified best way i thought,basically am trying to load an image into 2 different ImageViews which reside on `RecyclerView` using `Picasso`,the URL for the image into the ImageViews comes from server which i place in `Arraylist`,i can successfully retrieve one of the image url,but the other i am unable.

I have a Class for background networking activity which gives me the array

**BackgroundTask.java:**

```
package hilz.jsonrecyc;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask  {
    Context cxt;
    Activity activity;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<FruitPojo> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();

    BackgroundTask(Context cxt){
        this.cxt= cxt;
        activity= (Activity) cxt;

    }

    String json_string =  "http://10.0.3.2/fruits/l_news_details.php";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(cxt);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter= new RecyclerAdapter(cxt,arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        try {
            URL url= new URL(json_string);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream= httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                builder.append(line+"\n");
            }

            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            String json_string= builder.toString().trim();

            JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(json_string);
            JSONArray jsonArray= jsonObject.getJSONArray("Server_Response");
            int count= 0;
            while (count<jsonArray.length()){
                JSONObject jo= jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                FruitPojo fruitPojo= new FruitPojo(jo.getString("title"),jo.getString("photo"),jo.getString("photosh"));
                count++;
                publishProgress(fruitPojo);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object[] values) {
        arrayList.add((FruitPojo) values[0]);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
    }
}
```

I have a FruitPojo class modified to store a photo and title

```
package hilz.jsonrecyc;

public class FruitPojo {

    private String title,photos,photosh;

    public FruitPojo(String title, String photos,String photosh) {
        this.photos = photos;
        this.title = title;
        this.photosh= photosh;
    }

    public String getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    public void setPhotos(String photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPhotosh() {
        return photosh;
    }

    public void setPhotosh(String photosh) {
        this.photosh = photosh;
    }
}
```

I have a recycler Adapter class which checks to see if its a header(containng imageview) or List(containg photo and title), I want to get the URL from the same arraylist to use to load in Picasso.

**Adapter Class:**

```
package hilz.jsonrecyc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>{
    private static final int TYPE_HEAD=0;
    private static final int TYPE_LIST=1;
    ArrayList<FruitPojo> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();

    Context ctx;
    public RecyclerAdapter(Context ctx,ArrayList<FruitPojo> arrayList){
        this.arrayList= arrayList;
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        if (viewType==TYPE_HEAD) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
            RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
            return recyclerViewHolder;
        }
        else if (viewType==TYPE_LIST){

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
            RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view,viewType);
            return recyclerViewHolder;

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {




        if(holder.viewtype==TYPE_LIST){

            FruitPojo  fruitPojo= arrayList.get(position -1);
            holder.Textview_Title.setText(fruitPojo.getTitle());
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(fruitPojo.getPhotos())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.unloaded)
                    .resize(70,70)
                    .into(holder.imageViewL);

        }
        else if (holder.viewtype==TYPE_HEAD){


            FruitPojo  fruitPojo= arrayList.get(position -1);
            holder.Textview_Title.setText(fruitPojo.getTitle());
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(fruitPojo.getPhotos())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.unloaded)
                    .resize(70,70)
                    .into(holder.imageViewL);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size()+1;
    }

    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        int viewtype;
        TextView Textview_Title;
        ImageView imageViewL,imageViewH;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView,int viewtype) {

            super(itemView);


            if (viewtype==TYPE_HEAD){

                this.viewtype=TYPE_HEAD;
                imageViewH= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_header);
            }
            else if (viewtype==TYPE_LIST){
                this.viewtype=TYPE_LIST;

                Textview_Title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
                imageViewL= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv);



            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position==0){
            return TYPE_HEAD;
        }
        else {
            return TYPE_LIST;
        }
    }
}
```

Note!!!!!!!!!!!!! : if i change from:

```
  FruitPojo  fruitPojo= arrayList.get(position -1);


        if(holder.viewtype==TYPE_LIST){


            holder.Textview_Title.setText(fruitPojo.getTitle());
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(fruitPojo.getPhotos())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.unloaded)
                    .resize(70,70)
                    .into(holder.imageViewL);

        }
        else if (holder.viewtype==TYPE_HEAD){



            holder.Textview_Title.setText(fruitPojo.getTitle());
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(fruitPojo.getPhotos())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.unloaded)
                    .resize(70,70)
                    .into(holder.imageViewL);


        }
```

To:

```
    if(holder.viewtype==TYPE_LIST){

        FruitPojo  fruitPojo= arrayList.get(position -1);
        holder.Textview_Title.setText(fruitPojo.getTitle());
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(fruitPojo.getPhotos())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.unloaded)
                .resize(70,70)
                .into(holder.imageViewL);

    }
    else if (holder.viewtype==TYPE_HEAD){

}
```

The application works well at this point but i need to Set the imageview of header using URL i can change in server.

Layouts:

Row.xml (row layout of recyclerviw)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv"/>
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:text="The Title Goes Here.........."
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"

     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Header Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       android:id="@+id/iv_header"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

displaylist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="hilz.jsonrecyc.DisplayList">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

DisplayList.java

```
package hilz.jsonrecyc;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
```

This is the Logcat showing me arraylist is null.

```
public class DisplayList extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_list_layout);


        BackgroundTask backgroundTask= new BackgroundTask(DisplayList.this);
        backgroundTask.execute();
    }
}
```

This is Logcat:

> 06-01 07:47:49.440 5228-5228/hilz.jsonrecyc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main Process: hilz.jsonrecyc, PID: 5228
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1 at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310) at
>   hilz.jsonrecyc.RecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.java:76)
>   at
>   hilz.jsonrecyc.RecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.java:17)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5217) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5250)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4487)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1961)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1370)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1333)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:562)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2900)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3071)
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514) at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514) at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514) at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038) at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703) at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557) at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466) at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579) at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514) at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580) at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550) at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 06-01
>   07:52:49.554 5228-5228/hilz.jsonrecyc I/Process: Sending signal. PID:
>   5228 SIG: 9

So my main question is why is the arraylist not null in the TYPE_LIST but it becomes null in TYPE_HEAD

Comment: hi friend, did you check jsonArray.length() in doInBackground?

Comment: why are you  writing position -1

Comment: position 0 -1 = -1 so just pass position.

Comment: @KDeogharkar is right, in getView of an adapter the position is already a index

Comment: Why so much code??

Comment: your are getting list item count by setting list size and +1 please remove 
arrayList.size()+1;
and return actual list size
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

Comment: How do i solve?? am amateur,isnt the -1 for extra row ??

Comment: get the actual list size  like  "return arrayList.size()"

Comment: Ganesh that did the trick,thanks

Comment: @Mihriban Please, don't reformat stacktraces as quotes, it really harms readability.

Comment: While setting position =0 works,i have just realised it omits the first value in the arraylist,which reminded me why it was set to -0